# OG Pixel , I can only get to stock bootloader. device is not booting. How can I resurrect the device?

Tags: unbricking, google-pixel

just checking if my device is permanently bricked or there is a chance to resurrect it? I can only get to bootloader.

device is stock
I cannot get to recovery mode (stuck on google logo)
I cannot boot to OS (also stuck on google logo)

the only I can get is boot loader.

fastboot oem unlock get this error

```
FAILED (remote: 'oem unlock is not allowed')
fastboot: error: Command failed
```

adb devices does not show my device.

using https://flash.android.com/ it says device not supported (only pixel 2 and up)

any chance to revive this ??

also tried dePixel8, but no luck

```
adb push dePixel8 /data/local/tmp
adb: error: failed to get feature set: no devices/emulators found
```

thank you

```
fastboot flash recovery C:\IT\twrp-3.5.0_9-0-sailfish.img
Sending 'recovery' (26477 KB)                      OKAY [  0.760s]
Writing 'recovery'                                 (bootloader) Command is not supported.
(bootloader) Please unlock device to enable this command.
FAILED (remote: '')
fastboot: error: Command failed
```

Comment: you can change boot slots from fastboot and try to enter recovery. once in recovery flash Full OTA Image

Comment: Ok. Let me try tomorrow thank you for the suggestions

Comment: check download mode for bootloader version